Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig: gpg: Can't check signature: unknown pubkey algorithm
Tried keyring update; didn't help.
gpg --homedir ~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --list-keys shows expired keys. Emacs version is GNU Emacs 29.4 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2024-07-05, on Windows. Any idea how to fix this?
